# Quais os tipos de suspensões que existem?

Tags: debate, suporte, suspensão

Navegando pela query https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/671139/recent-banned-users notei 3 tipos de suspensão:

manipulação de votos:

> Esta conta foi temporariamente suspensa por **manipulação de votos.**

network-wide (creio que significa que foi suspenso na rede toda da SE):

> Esta conta foi temporariamente suspensa **network-wide**

Para que o usuário fique mais tranquilo:

> Esta conta foi temporariamente suspensa para **tranquilizar**

Esta foi a primeira vez que notei uma conta suspensa por *network-wide*, então fiquei com as dúvidas:

- Quais os tipos suspensões que existem?
- Ou o texto do motivo como tranquilizar, network-wide e manipulação de votos são "strings" e o texto da suspensão pode ser customizada?

Answer (score 10):

Não sei dizer, até porque os moderadores não usam nada disto diretamente. Não há relação direta em todos os casos que aparece no perfil do usuário suspenso e o motivo que ele foi suspenso.

Obviamente que o *network-wide* não é feito por nós.

O "para tranquilizar" parece ser um guarda-chuva para vários motivos.

Existem vários motivos de moderação que não incluem suspensões. A descrição da suspensão nem sempre é pelo motivo da mensagem:

[image: Motivos de moderação]

Comment: Maneiro, creio que o `outras coisas...` confirma a minha suspeita, ainda sim não sei se isto muda a mensagem no perfil do usuário, mas de qualquer forma a resposta já deu um bom entendimento. +1

Comment: O que quer dizer "votos visados"?

Comment: @VictorStafusa "Targeted votes". Talvez melhor mudarmos para "Direcionamento de votos".

Answer (score 10):

Os motivos que existem estão [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89027/208518), tirando o "network-wide" que só foi implementado mais tarde. Estes são, portanto:

- por manipulação de votos
- para tranquilizar/acalmar
- por causa de contribuições de má-qualidade
- por conteúdo promocional (spam)

A suspensão em toda a rede (network-wide) só pode ser aplicada pelos [CMs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/208518), e é utilizada em casos extremos. Todos os outros são bastante auto-explicativos.

Comment: Excelente complemente!