# Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?

Tags: debate, respostas, comportamento

Tenho visto algumas respostas somente com código, sem uma única palavra de descrição e com uns quantos votos positivos. Para não me ficar por palavras deixo aqui algumas:

- [Somente números positivos em agregação SUM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304663/82711)
- [Como verificar parênteses de uma expressão algébrica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313295/82711)
- [Transformar texto em negrito com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/310628/82711)

Eu sei que no SOen este tipo de respostas é recorrente (hoje em dia já não tanto), mas sempre fiquei com a ideia que aqui no SOpt não era bem aceite. Até porque queremos ao máximo ter conteúdo de qualidade, que explique os problemas ao invés de despejar código para copy paste.

Já tentei até dialogar com um destes usuários no passado mas sem qualquer sucesso, e que gerou uma discussão bem ferverosa.

Questões:

- Estou errado no meu julgamento e estas respostas aqui são perfeitamente aceitáveis?
- É possível de fazer algo sem ser votar negativo?
- O voto negativo é correto nestes casos?
- Deveria sinalizar como conteúdo de baixa qualidade apesar de o código resolver o problema?

Comment: As vezes eu não coloco comentários fora do código, mas sim como comentários do próprio código. O importante é quem perguntou entendeu como você resolveu o problema dele, não necessariamente tornar explicito o que foi feito.

Comment: @CypherPotato Isso na minha opinião cai no "suporte técnico" (como o Guilherme também disse na resposta dele) uma vez que você apenas mete o código para resolver o problema e não explica nada. Acaba também por não fazer o usuário melhorar no futuro pois ele nem percebeu qual era o problema, apenas copiou cegamente o seu código porque funcionava. Embora esteja uma pergunta nos links que tem comentários a explicar eu referia-me especificamente às que não explicam de forma nenhuma, nem em comentários.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aceitáveis sim, mas serão úteis apenas ao autor da pergunta, não são respostas que de fato orientam e explicam o código, então acaba por ficar no *"suporte técnico"*, o que não é bem o objetivo da comunidade.

Creio que o *downvote* em respostas do tipo (não estou dizendo das respostas deste autor, mas qualquer resposta que não explique o código) são aceitáveis como indicador de que as respostas podem melhorar.

Claro que infelizmente existem autores que não aceitam nem mesmo comentários, mesmo que não recebam *downvotes* de avaliação como "pode melhorar", simplesmente porque tem resistência em entender como a comunidade funciona e qual o nosso objetivo, que é ajudar mais do que quem pergunta, mas ajudar a visitantes futuros também, por isso uma explicação sobre como funciona o código e o porque daquela maneira (acaso exista mais de uma) é a mais aceitável é totalmente ideal para o bem estar/saúde da comunidade toda.

Isso eu falo de qualquer resposta, e não deste autor em questão.

---

Sobre as respostas linkadas, essa aqui está explicada:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/310628/3635

É que ele explicou dentro do código, com comentários, claro que ele não explicou o comportamento das regex, mas regex é um caso complicado e complexo de explicar, então do meu ponto de vista esta resposta específica está boa sim.

As demais realmente seria interessante ter uma explicação para que assim fiquem respostas interessantes não só para quem perguntou no momento, mas para futuros visitantes, já que o maior propósito da comunidade é este, ser útil além do momento.

Comentar sempre que possível pedindo para o autor é um caminho interessante e quem recebe o comentário tem que entender como uma crítica construtiva para o bem de toda comunidade.

Comment: Nesse exemplo de resposta, esse usuário aparece com 1 de pontuação, mas tenho certeza de já ter visto ele com mais

Comment: @RicardoPontual se entrar no perfil dele vai notar que ele foi penalizado com o "cantinho da disciplina", o motivo ao certo eu não sei, mas quando vc recebe um pênalti no site é por algo sério, isso tem explicado no META, sobre usuários com 1 de pontuação.

Comment: Nem sabia que tinha isso

Comment: @RicardoPontual https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6653/quais-os-tipos-de-suspens%C3%B5es-que-existem

Comment: Ele fora suspenso de novo? Eu interagi com ele hoje mesmo e estava tão amigável...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado foi no chat né?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como comentário em uma resposta dele mesmo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado estranho, não sei bem como funciona a suspensão, mas não deveria ser possivel ele comentar, só se ele criou outra conta

Answer (score 12):

De forma geral o que eu faço, recomendo e deveria ser regra (IMHO) é analisar o contexto sempre, há casos que até cabe isso, muitas vezes porque a pergunta não é lá grande coisa também. Se achar que é um caso ruim, e considerando que não tem nada errado nela considere não fazer nada.

Mas há exageros que vira algo pouco útil, e pode até responder, mas não há esforço. Quando é exagerado, e apesar de ser uma tentativa de resposta não ajuda de fato, um negativo pode caber:

[image: Não é útil]

Aconselho nesses caso um comentário para ajudar a pessoa entender que falta algo para que ela seja útil.

Em casos da pessoa ser conhecida por não gostar de ser interpelada a melhorar, pode sinalizar para a moderação (mas só faça isso em casos recorrentes da pessoa. Se a conversa descambar, procure evitar entrar "na pilha" (sei como é difícil com certas pessoas), e sinalize para os moderadores tomarem providência. Usuários que estão aqui só para "causar" serão progressivamente punidos. Usuários que erram pontualmente sempre terão oportunidades de melhorar. Existe uma diferença entre má vontade ou mesmo má fé e ser uma pessoa difícil.

Em alguns casos pode caber uma sinalização de baixa qualidade para moderadores avaliarem.

Mas elas são aceitáveis também, não podemos sinalizar como "não é uma resposta". E mesmo negativação pode ser exagero. Em alguns casos até cabe positivo.

Comment: Não fazer nada é literalmente o que eu tenho feito, mas fiquei na duvida mesmo se seria o mais apropriado.