# Respostas sem código não são respostas?

Tags: debate

Recentemente vi a resposta de um usuário do **SOpt**, onde ele dava a resposta da pergunta dizendo exatamente o que o cara **teria que desenvolver**, porém não postou em sua resposta código algum ou codificou pra ele.

Resumindo, sua resposta não estava de tudo errada mas foi negativada pela comunidade provavelmente por não conter o código.

Para ser realmente considerado uma resposta temos que entregar o código pronto para quem pergunta?

Link da pergunta: [Filtrar palavras contidas no BindingSource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372013/filtrar-palavras-contidas-no-bindingsource)

Comment: A pergunta tem o código, descreve o erro e qual deveria ser o resultado, então uma resposta deveria sim mostrar o código certo (além, é claro, de explicar pq o código original não funcionou, etc, pois ter **apenas** o código sem explicação [também é ruim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/112052)). A meu ver a resposta, apesar de não estar errada, está incompleta pq no fim não resolve o problema de fato, só "dá umas dicas", e a ideia do site é ter respostas completas (dicas podem ser dadas nos comentários). Eu não daria positivo nem negativo, mas não tiro a razão de quem negativou

Comment: Eu acabei de pegar uma análise deste mesmo carinha, mas uma pergunta diferente. Ele deu a resposta explicativa, também sem códigos. A formatação da pergunta é ruim, ele usa gírias e há erros de concordância, mas afinal, aqui não é um site sobre Língua Portuguesa xD... Portanto, considerei como OK, visto uma vez que ele respondeu a pergunta, usando as palavras dele. **Não creio que exista um padrão de respostas aqui no SOPT.**

Comment: Com certeza não, afinal a [pergunta e resposta mais votada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402) da comunidade não tem código algum

Answer (score 13):

> Para ser realmente considerado uma resposta temos que entregar o código pronto para quem pergunta?

Não. Arrisco-me a dizer até que as melhores respostas do site atualmente não mostram código algum.

A resposta em questão foi negativada, mas é importante analisar todos os quesitos. Será mesmo que foi negativada por não ter código? Por exemplo, eu tive que reler a resposta pelo menos 5 vezes e ainda não entendi bem o que o autor quis dizer, talvez pela minha ignorância perante a ferramenta em questão, mas principalmente porque o autor não usou pontuação alguma no texto. E isso é um ponto constantemente discutido no Meta: a comunicação através do site é inteiramente escrita, não temos como nos comunicar por áudio ou vídeo, então saber ler e escrever é primordial. Elaborar um texto gramaticalmente correto e pontuado é essencial para transmitir exatamente aquilo que você deseja.

Basicamente, acho que o problema da resposta citada não é a ausência de código.

---

Importante salientar também que houve uma edição bruta na resposta. Qualquer voto, seja ele negativo ou voto de "não resposta", pode ser sido feito **antes** da edição. Perceba que antes da edição a resposta não era uma resposta concreta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Claramente o problema é do conteúdo como um todo ou estado inicial da (não) resposta e não falta de código. Em alguns casos entrgar código é que é ruim.

Answer (score 5):

Como comentei, vi outra resposta dele em outra pergunta, seguindo o mesmo método: gírias e sem código, nem formatação. Mas ele explicou e deu sua resposta para resolver o problema, e afinal, não é isso que importa?

Como Woss disse:

> *Será mesmo que foi negativada por não ter código?*

Realmente, vi muitas respostas dadas que não foram sequer colocado um número na publicação, e foram aceitas e bem votadas.

Pelo que sei, não existe um padrão de respostas no SOpt, e portanto, não vejo problemas na resposta dele. Ele respondeu a pergunta, mas de seu jeito de explicar.

O que devemos fazer, é editar a publicação para que fique o mais formatada e legível possível, corrigindo erros ortográficos e removendo gírias, uma vez que são desnecessárias aqui no site.

E deixarmos o trabalho da pergunta ser aceita ou não para a comunidade.

Comment: Por mais que eu seja novo aqui, entendo dessa forma também.

Answer (score 2):

O meu ponto de vista é que quando recorremos à uma ajuda, não devemos olhar se a resposta de quem tenta nos ajudar está cheia de flores, cores e bolinhos primavera ou com o português devidamente correto.

Se a resposta pelo menos tem um embasamento, e deu um caminho para o cara seguir, acho que não deve ser negativado por causa disso, no máximo não receber voto algum negativo.

Ao invés de negativar o cara que tentou ajudar e explicar do jeito dele, por que não escrever uma resposta melhor do que a dele pra tentar ser selecionado?

Comment: Concordo que floreios e firulas são desnecessários, mas português correto eu acho importante. Claro que não precisamos ser *grammar nazis*, e eu mesmo cometo erros de gramática e/ou digitação, mas é preciso estabelecer um padrão mínimo: pontuação, clareza no texto, sem muitas gírias, etc. Se não dá pra entender o texto, também não dá para avaliar se a resposta está certa. Dito isso, ainda acho que respostas incompletas (só dão o caminho, mas não resolvem) deveriam ser colocadas como comentários. Claro que há exceções, mas não é o caso aqui.

Comment: Concordo com tudo que disse. No mínimo o portugues deve ser aplicado, pra pelo menos mostrar o mínimo de interesse de ajuda e não apenas pontuar.

Comment: Cada um julga e vota como quiser. Se quem fez a pergunta se satisfaz com a ajuda recebida e quer votar positivo, sem problemas. Porém o objetivo do site é que cada pergunta possa idealmente ajudar ao maior número possível de pessoas além de quem perguntou. Por isso o site tem um formato determinado e seus padrões de qualidade, e justamente por causa deles é que se tornou um site importante. Então outros membros da comunidade, em geral os mais participativos, vão votar com isso em mente.

Comment: Levando em consideração que esta é a maior comunidade de perguntas e respostas, eu valorizo demais uma resposta bem elaborada (por mais que ainda esteja apanhando em alguns quesitos kkkk), e isso não diz respeito a somente conhecimentos técnicos, mas com aspectos gramaticalmente corretos. Eu eté já observei que a maioria das perguntas com maiores votações tem sua estrutura, falando gramaticalmente, mais bem feita.