# A maneira certa de responder uma pergunta

Tags: debate, respostas

Sou um usuário novo no Stack Overflow mas já vi vários posts de debates e pensei que poderia trazer um pra comunidade. Quem quer uma comunidade mais limpa se esforça pra deixar claro que existe uma maneira certa de fazer uma pergunta, formatar o texto, mostrar que já pesquisou, mostrar tentativas e etc. Mas será que também cabe uma maneira certa de responder?

Eu devo ensinar pra pessoa como programar ou apenas apontar o que está errado e uma possível solução. É melhor ignorar perguntas mal feitas e estudantes querendo a resposta de um exercício ou simplesmente responder?

Por exemplo, [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479154/fazer-busca-em-uma-matrizlista-de-lista/479156#479156), a pessoa tinha um problema e eu indiquei pra ela o problema e como resolver, mas parece que simplesmente não é suficiente, a resposta dada como correta praticamente deu uma aula de Python, que está no tutorial da linguagem, o que eu acho que não incentiva ninguém a aprender e incentiva perguntas mal feitas.

Comment: Sugiro começar melhorando as habilidades de produção de texto, tanto aqui quanto lá fica muito difícil entender o que escreveu. Tem um monte de assunto diferente em um parágrafo só, falta coesão no raciocínio. Importante deixar claro o foco do debate. Talvez antes de postar fosse o caso de definir a linha de raciocínio e fazeer parágrafos individuais sobre cada ponto (com começo, meio e fim). Note, dá para identificar algumas queixas e perguntas, mas é dificil entender o objetivo geral. Objetividade e foco é fundamental aqui.

Comment: E espero que entenda o comentário como parte da orientação de por onde começar, e não como uma crítica pela crítica. O fato é que, quanto menos esforço o leitor precisar para entender você, mais alcance você terá para transmitir a mensagem.

Comment: Não achei a outra resposta extensa e nem uma aula, achei na verdade bem curta e direta, explica o essencial do que a pessoa precisa entender antes de usar. Sobre a sua resposta, eu não sei o motivo dos downvotes, mas eu também não entendi a sua explicação sobre o código, talvez se reformular o texto ele fique mais claro, principalmente indicando o que mudou tecnicamente nas partes que mudou. Acho que sobre "maneira de responder" e votar é totalmente pessoal [...]

Comment: [...] se recebeu downvotes foram ações pessoais de individuos e não algo que defina que sua resposta esta errada, pode ser só que acham que ela possa melhorar, downvote não é dislike, é basicamente isso: a pessoa que votou acha que você deve melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Lembrando que seus pontos já permitem participar do chat oficial da rede, acessível pelo menu superior do site - Em especial, a sala [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), que é vinculada ao Stack Overflow em Português.

Comment: Já foi levantado pelos colegas, mas em resumo a resposta dada como correta além de resolver o problema do usuário, embasa o leitor para resolver problemas similares. Quanto a sua resposta no momento está incompreensível seria bom a editar tornando a mais simples de ler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro vou comentar sobre sua resposta, depois falo sobre respostas de uma forma mais geral.

---

### Sobre a sua resposta

Pelo que entendi da [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479156/112052), você sugeriu que mudasse apenas um trecho do código e o restante ficasse igual. Pois bem, se fizermos isso, ficaria assim:

```python
# trecho igual ao da pergunta
def busca(setor):
    matriz = [["Adalberto Ferreira", "566", "Contabilidade", "(21)84564-5248"],
              ["Juliana Vasconcelos", "465", "RH", "(21)3555-4552"],
              ["Flavia Amorim", "565", "Contabilidade", "(21)2134-4845"]]
    nome = matriz[0][0], matriz[1][0], matriz[2][0]
    registro = matriz[0][1], matriz[1][1], matriz[2][1]
    setor = matriz[0][2], matriz[1][2], matriz[2][2]
    telefone = matriz[0][3], matriz[1][3], matriz[2][3]

    # daqui pra baixo é o que você sugeriu mudar
    if setor == matriz[1][3]:
        return [nome[1][0:], registro[1][1:], telefone[1][3:]]
    else:
        return [[nome[0][0:], registro[0][1:], telefone[0][3:]], [nome[2][0:], registro[2][1:], telefone[2:][3:]]]
```

Será que funciona? [Vejamos](https://ideone.com/E2KecE):

```python
print(busca('Contabilidade')) # [['Adalberto Ferreira', '66', ')84564-5248'], ['Flavia Amorim', '65', ()]]
print(busca('RH')) # [['Adalberto Ferreira', '66', ')84564-5248'], ['Flavia Amorim', '65', ()]]
print(busca('Setor inexistente')) # [['Adalberto Ferreira', '66', ')84564-5248'], ['Flavia Amorim', '65', ()]]
```

A pergunta diz que a função deve fazer uma busca por setor e retornar o nome, o registro e o telefone dos funcionários daquele setor.

Mas seguindo a sua sugestão, a função **não** busca por setor: repare que ela sempre retorna a mesma coisa, independente do setor informado. Mesmo se eu informar um setor inexistente, o retorno sempre tem os mesmos funcionários.

Além disso, ela retorna parte do registro e do telefone, e não a informação completa (O registro do "Adalberto Ferreira" é "566" mas o retorno foi "66", o telefone também ficou "cortado"). E o segundo telefone é uma tupla vazia - `()` - e não uma string. Ou seja, uma confusão completa.

Portanto, sua resposta não resolve o problema (isso pode explicar os negativos). Então respondendo ao seu questionamento ("A maneira certa de responder uma pergunta"), o **mínimo** que uma resposta deveria ter é um código que funcione (que resolva o problema da pergunta) e uma explicação do mesmo ([se tiver só o código sem explicação, também é ruim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/112052)). Se seguir o que você sugeriu, não funciona, então a informação que tem na sua resposta não é o suficiente - sem contar que a explicação também é confusa ("*quando você abre o segundo colchete para acessar o elemento da matriz o interpretador como se você tivesse fazendo fatiamento já que você está trabalhando com strings*" - este trecho ficou meio confuso, talvez porque tenha faltado alguma palavra no trecho "o interpretador como se você estivesse fazendo", além de explicar melhor o que acontece).

Outro detalhe é que fazer `[0:]` em uma string é redundante, pois retornará a mesma string, e portanto é desnecessário. Na verdade, todos esses *slices* são desnecessários. Todo o problema começa porque o código da pergunta assume que a lista sempre tem 3 elementos e usa índices fixos, e esse é o pior jeito de trabalhar com listas, que é uma estrutura que pode ter qualquer tamanho. Qualquer solução que insista nesse erro estará errada (mesmo que "funcione").

---

### Sobre respostas em geral

Falando de forma mais geral, não precisa necessariamente "dar uma aula de programação" ao responder. Mas também não é para jogar sugestões e dicas de qualquer jeito.

Lembre-se que o [objetivo do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/112052) é formar um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, e as respostas devem ser úteis não apenas para quem pergunta, mas para qualquer pessoa que visite o site no futuro. Sendo assim, é importante dar uma solução correta (idealmente "a melhor possível", ou o mais próximo disso que você conseguir), explicando porque ela funciona, porque do outro jeito é pior, etc.

Claro que nada impede de dar uma solução não tão boa assim, desde que se avise que ela não é boa, explicando os motivos e limitações - pois aí também gera conhecimento que será útil aos futuros visitantes do site. Um dos problemas do site é que vejo muita "gambiarra" sendo sugerida e apresentada como se fosse uma solução válida, sem avisar que é gambiarra (e principalmente, sem explicar porque é gambiarra e os problemas que isso pode causar), e aí em vez de gerar conhecimento, pode acabar até prejudicando a pessoa (vide respostas que sugerem código vulnerável a SQL injection, só pra citar um exemplo).

Eu não acho que "dei uma aula", eu só expliquei que para buscar elementos de uma lista é melhor fazer um *loop* do que usar índices fixos, já que listas têm tamanho variável. Só dei uma solução um pouco mais geral, e aproveitei para resolver os outros problemas do código para que funcionasse (e também dei algumas sugestões de melhoria).

No fundo, isso cai no caso que já comentei [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8350/112052): se a pessoa diz "*Estou usando um taco de beisebol para pescar mas não está funcionando*", em vez de responder "*Acerte o peixe na cabeça*", eu prefiro responder "*Não use o taco, use vara e anzol*". Não precisa dar uma aula completa de pescaria, só explique porque usar o taco é ruim (em vez de insistir no erro e sugerir soluções bizarras/erradas) e mostre como fica mais fácil e correto com a ferramenta certa.

> *eu acho que não incentiva ninguém a aprender e incentiva perguntas mal feitas*

O que incentiva perguntas mal feitas são as pessoas que votam positivo e respondem a essas perguntas. Se viu uma pergunta mal feita, [sinalize](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)/vote para fechar, e/ou comente o que está errado para que a pessoa possa melhorá-la.

No caso da pergunta em questão, eu não diria que é o caso de fechar. Ela tem o código, diz o que ele deveria fazer e explica mais ou menos o problema. Claro que ela poderia ser melhorada com alguns exemplos e talvez uma descrição mais bem trabalhada, mas enfim, não está tão mal feita assim, se considerarmos a (falta de) qualidade atual do site.

Enfim, se a pergunta for bem feita, com um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e [dentro do escopo e das regras do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/112052), tanto faz se é exercício de faculdade de um estudante, um curioso/entusiasta ou um profissional experiente, pode-se responder sem problemas. O mesmo vale se a pergunta for mal feita: tanto faz se foi feita por um iniciante ou um usuário experiente com milhões de pontos, se estiver fora do escopo deve ser fechada.

É claro que - depois de um tempo participando do site você começa a perceber - iniciantes e estudantes **geralmente** têm mais dificuldade de elaborar uma pergunta bem feita e dentro do escopo, e a maioria só joga o enunciado e espera que alguém faça tudo pra eles, mas isso não quer dizer que eles não são bem vindos. Se a pergunta estiver no escopo, pode até ter sido feita por um robô ou um cachorro, que não teria problema nenhum em responder.

---

### Considerações finais

Apenas para complementar o que foi dito acima:

- claro que nem toda resposta precisa necessariamente ter código (se a pergunta for conceitual, por exemplo). Mas se a pergunta é sobre um código que não funciona, então no mínimo você deveria fazê-lo funcionar (mesmo que a solução seja jogar tudo fora e reescrever - que é quase o que eu fiz no caso em questão)
- respostas não precisam necessariamente ser "aulas". Mas como a ideia do site é ser um repositório de conhecimento, no qual as respostas devem ser úteis também para futuros visitantes, é sempre bom e desejável ter alguma explicação, por mais básica que seja. E se quiser alongar um pouco esta explicação, fica a seu critério - desde que seja pertinente e não fuja muito do escopo da pergunta.
- de forma geral, cada um responde como quer e encara as consequências (se tiver qualidade, é mais provável que receba votos positivos, caso contrário, receberá negativos), então cabe a você escolher como quer responder daqui pra frente

  - lembrando que se tiver muitas respostas negativadas, o [sistema pode te bloquear automaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) - encare isso como mais um incentivo para escrever respostas de qualidade :-)

Comment: É, eu realmente dei uma vacilei com a resposta não testando direito o código e com a explicação, nem tinha percebido, e agora também entendi melhor o propósito do site, valeu.

Comment: @HenriqueHott, Ao editar sua resposta melhorando a qualidade do conteúdo apresentado você pode reverter seus negativos e ainda buscar alguns *upvotes* pois ao editar a sua resposta, a pergunta onde ela está anexada é posta novamente em evidência na home do Stack Overflow em Português disponibilizando seu novo conteúdo a outra rodada de análises da comunidade. Causa efeito, melhorando o seu conteúdo a comunidade saberá reconhecer o 
esforço. Veja dicas de como formular uma resposta em [Como escrever uma boa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).