# Como evitar receber votos negativos?

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Gostaria da opinião da comunidade quanto a resposta publicada na pergunta seguinte:

[PYTHON: NameError: name is not defined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/516190/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined/516199#516199)

Achei notório que o foco da pergunta é sobre o motivo de uma **variável aparentemente declarada, não estar sendo visualizada pelo compilador**. Acredito que a resposta apresentada responda objetiva e satisfatoriamente a pergunta.
Visto que o algoritmo em si e sua análise quanto a outras possíveis inconsistências não são objetos dessa resposta, foi evidenciado apenas a raiz do problema relatado na pergunta sobre a visibilidade da variável `v0`, cabendo ao usuário realizar as melhorias necessárias na aplicação para solucionar demais problemas que, porventura, existam no código.
Sabendo que o erro gerado `NameError: name 'v0' is not defined` e, agora sanado, e não disse que seja a melhor forma de saná-lo, mas sim que é uma das formas de sanar, devendo a sua aplicabilidade ser verificada e validada pelo usuário.
Conforme relatado, essa resposta visa sanar a pergunta do usuário e possibilitar o avanço na lógica do algoritmo, visto que até o nome do arquivo é definido como sendo um rascunho como evidenciado na mensagem de erro **ep03-rascunho.py**, então cabe ao usuário realizar as demais melhorias e, com essas melhorias, aprimorar a lógica de programação e caso precise de ajuda relacionado a outro trecho do código, poderá solicitá-la por meio de uma nova pergunta.

Fica a pergunta: **Como evitar receber votos negativos ao responder somente o que foi perguntado pelo usuário?**

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127848/discussion-on-question-by-clarck-maciel-como-evitar-receber-votos-negativos) - quem quiser acompanhar o desenrolar do assunto e/ou acrescentar algo, pode utilizar o link fornecido.

Answer (score 6):

O problema daquela pergunta, no fundo, é entender sobre o escopo de variáveis. O `NameError` é apenas uma consequência de não entender isso (pois ele tenta acessar uma variável fora do escopo no qual ela está definida).

A solução, a meu ver, não é simplesmente tentar corrigir o `NameError` a qualquer custo. Isso é tratar o sintoma, e não a causa. Para tratar a causa, deve-se explicar o que é o escopo de uma variável, para que serve uma função, etc, e aí nem precisaria de `global` e outros artifícios. Eu sempre acho melhor tratar a raiz do problema, em vez de só arrumar o erro de compilação e achar que está tudo certo.

Além disso, dá para perceber que a pessoa que perguntou é iniciante (nada errado com isso, todos já fomos um dia), então simplesmente ensinar a usar `global` sem alertar para os problemas é - na minha opinião - irresponsável. Já que é para ensinar, vamos fazer direito (não precisa fazer uma dissertação sobre "os malefícios de variáveis globais", mas pelo menos uma frase indicando isso seria bom ter - na minha resposta coloquei alguns links sobre o assunto, por exemplo).

---

**Falando de forma mais geral**, a ideia do site - pelo menos a ideia original, que infelizmente não parece ser compartilhada por muitos atualmente - é formar um repositório de conhecimento, com as respostas mais corretas possíveis (isso é o oposto do *helpdesk*, do "*faz qualquer coisa que funcione*", é o contrário da filosofia "*compilou, tá valendo*" - [funcionar é diferente de estar certo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png)).

Vou repetir o que já disse [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8478/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8350/112052): se a pessoa chega dizendo "*estou usando um taco de beisebol para pescar mas não está funcionando*", o que você faz? Muitos preferem sugerir gambiarras como "*acerte o peixe na cabeça*", ou "*amarre uma linha no taco*". Pode até "funcionar", mas não é o ideal. Eu prefiro dizer "*não use o taco, use uma vara de pescar*", além de explicar porque o taco não é a melhor ferramenta para a tarefa. Não tenho problemas em reescrever o código se achar que é melhor (tentar fazer com que o taco de beisebol se torne uma vara de pescar daria tanto trabalho que é melhor jogá-lo fora e recomeçar tudo do zero).

Infelizmente o mais comum hoje em dia tem sido a de insistir em "soluções" com o taco de beisebol, alegando que "*só quis me basear no código da pergunta*". Daí surgem respostas com gambiarras, com *SQL injection*, ou que resolvem um problema mas acabam criando outros. No fundo isso acaba desensinando, fazendo com que a qualidade do site - que já não anda boa - piore cada vez mais.

---

O que me fez gostar do Stack Overflow - e um dos principais fatores do site ter se tornado o que é hoje - foram as respostas que vão além da pergunta. São as que enxergam além do simples erro e geram conhecimento, por caminhos que nem o autor da pergunta imaginava. Muitas vezes quem pergunta nem faz ideia disso, por isso que às vezes se limitar apenas ao que foi perguntado acaba gerando uma resposta ruim, ou pelo menos uma não tão ideal assim (tendo em vista o objetivo de formar o repositório de conhecimento).

Claro que tem casos e casos, tem muitas perguntas que não dão margem para ir além e aí tudo bem se limitar ao problema específico. Mas tem casos em que só corrigir um problema específico não é o suficiente, principalmente se você deixa outros mais graves em aberto (e claro que, se for fugir muito do escopo da pergunta, não precisa corrigir todos, mas pelo menos deixe uma observação alertando sobre isso, para que a pessoa não ache que está tudo bem).

Aqui na internet temos uma ferramenta incrível para compartilhar conhecimento, e temos que tentar usá-la da melhor forma possível. **<papo-de-velho>** Na minha época de faculdade as informações eram mais difíceis de serem obtidas, tínhamos que caçá-las em trocentos fóruns e blogs, e mesmo assim era complicado filtrar o que era confiável ou não. **</papo-de-velho>** Hoje temos a chance de ensinar direito desde o início, em vez de só formar uma geração de copiadores de código. Tínhamos que aproveitar melhor isso...

Comment: Mas na resposta dada consta: "O problema é que a variável não está sendo usada como variável `global`, **por isso essas variáveis só existem no escopo da função.**". Essa parte não deixou claro que o motivo é o escopo da variável? Sendo uma solução possível a utilização de uma variável global para que o compilador passe a "ver" essa variável.

Comment: @ClarckMaciel Mas ainda tem os outros problemas que mencionei: não diz que usar `global` não é a solução ideal (da forma que está, passa a impressão de que é a solução ideal), "resolve" um problema mas cria outros (no final ele só tem os dados do último alienígena, e perde os restantes; sem contar o próprio fato de usar variáveis globais), etc. Enfim, mesmo que tenha mencionado o problema, ainda acho que está tratando o sintoma e não a causa. Mas essa é minha visão, não consigo ler os pensamentos dos outros (tem 3 negativos ali, mas _imagino_ que os motivos tenham sido similares)

Comment: bem, o programa possuía vários outros problemas, eu havia testado, mas, como disse, lá há indícios de ser um rascunho, cabendo, no que entendo, ao usuário tratar das demais correções necessárias. Podendo fazer as correções, fica melhor, mas utilizando o `global` também seria possível resolver. Acredito que o pessoal devia fazer semelhante a você, que achou que a resposta não estava boa e postou uma que na sua concepção e de outros (4 positivos) é melhor.  O "resolveu" do usuário, entendi como "destravou", ou seja, ele entendeu o motivo do erro naquele contexto.